# Tough automation issue - subscribe to email subscriptions

Tags: smtp, mandrill, mailgun, inbound

The problem....

We have a Web Application that bring in articles from various sources such as (google, bing, yandex).

We wish to add another source.  The source is email subscriptions from scientific journals of which there are thousands.

We want our userbase to be able to signup for email subscriptions and pull them into the Web Application.  As the subscription process requires an email and a confirmation of email step, this is pretty user unfriendly if an admin has to go and check emails all the time.  We have a proposed workflow and would be interested to implement something like the following.

Proposed workflow

- 1. User goes to a custom subscription management page in our web
     application
  2. User enters the name of the subscription.
  3. User presses 'save' User receives a unique email address from the application (i.e. subscription1233167845@mydomain.com)
  4. user then takes this email and uses it to sign up for the email subscription with the scientific journal
  5. system receives email from scientific journal asking for confirmation
  6. system automatically verifies email address
  7. email alerts received for journal

From here there are 2 possibilities

- 1) the application parses all resources in email and extracts links
  which are submitted to the applications custom crawler

  2) information
  is scraped directly from email and added to the web application list
  of articles

can it be done?  Do you have a better way??  Thoughts?